# Collapsed Grid in StackPanel change position of other controls in StackPanel

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-store-apps, windows-8.1, visibility

I have this `Xaml` Page:

```
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Grid x:Name="inkGrid0" Margin="0,0,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" >
                    <Canvas x:Name="inkCanvas0" Width="570">
                        <Canvas.Background>
                            <ImageBrush x:Name="DImage0" ImageSource="{Binding}"/>
                        </Canvas.Background>
                    </Canvas>
                </Grid>
                <Grid x:Name="inkGrid1" Margin="0,0,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Right" >
                    <Canvas x:Name="inkCanvas1" Width="570">
                        <Canvas.Background>
                            <ImageBrush x:Name="DImage1" ImageSource="{Binding}"/>
                        </Canvas.Background>
                    </Canvas>
                </Grid>
            </StackPanel>
```

Once I add `inkGrid0.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed` to my code, the `inkGrid1` take the left position of the `inkGrid0` which is now collapsed.

How to make `inkGrid1` at its place when `inkGrid0` is collapsed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply set it's opacity to 0 if you don't want to deal with resizing etc.However you must consider interactions like tapping or clicking.

Setting an opacity instead of Visibility is much usefull in terms of performance and it's easy.

Comment: Well Opacity works but isn't there a real solution for that? @jerrynixon

Comment: You might use Grid ColumnDefinitions with MinWidth property.

Instead of using Stackpanel , use Grid with 2 ColumnDefinitions :

<Grid>
 <Grid.ColumnDeifinitions>
  <ColumnDefinition MinWidth="570"/>
  <ColumnDefinition MinWidth="*"/>
 </Grid.ColumnDeifinitions>

<Grid x:Name="inkGrid0" Grid.Column="0">
</Grid>

<Grid x:Name="inkGrid1" Grid.Column="1">

</Grid>
</Grid>

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Visibility.Hidden`. However, I propose a more elegant solution which would be to use a `Grid` and `ColumnDefinitions`.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <!-- Your Controls Here -->
    <Grid x:Name="inkGrid0" ... />

    <Grid x:Name="inkGrid1" Grid.Column="1" ... />
</Grid>
```

Comment: There's only Visible and Collapse under Visibility, Hidden does not exist. I tried adding `Grid.ColumnDefinition` but it didn't work.

Comment: My bad, didn't see you were windows 8.1. `ColumnDefinitions` are not available in a `StackPanel`, make sure you are using a `Grid`.

Answer (score -1):

```
 <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Grid x:Name="inkGrid0" Margin="0,0,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Background="Black" Visibility="Hidden">
            <Canvas x:Name="inkCanvas0" Width="570">
                <Canvas.Background>
                    <ImageBrush x:Name="DImage0" />
                </Canvas.Background>
            </Canvas>
        </Grid>
        <Grid x:Name="inkGrid1" Margin="0,0,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Background="Blue"  >
            <Canvas x:Name="inkCanvas1" Width="570">
                <Canvas.Background>
                    <ImageBrush x:Name="DImage1" />
                </Canvas.Background>
            </Canvas>
        </Grid>
    </StackPanel>
```

You can use Visibility.Hidden   or use fixed  column width

```
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="570" />
                <ColumnDefinition />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid x:Name="inkGrid01" Margin="0,0,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Background="Black" Visibility="Collapsed">
                <Canvas x:Name="inkCanvas01" Width="570">
                    <Canvas.Background>
                        <ImageBrush x:Name="DImage111" />
                    </Canvas.Background>
                </Canvas>
            </Grid>
            <Grid x:Name="inkGrid11" Margin="0,0,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Background="Blue" Grid.Column="1">
                <Canvas x:Name="inkCanvas11" Width="570">
                    <Canvas.Background>
                        <ImageBrush x:Name="DImage11" />
                    </Canvas.Background>
                </Canvas>
            </Grid>

        </Grid>

    </StackPanel>
```